# Reset Date input using Javascript - Why using declared variable doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm trying to reset a date if the input date is today or in the past, just wondering why doesn't `date = ""` work since I already declared the variable "date" earlier, but I found that it works if I type `document.getElementById("date").value = "";` instead, when (I presume) they're the same thing?

```js
function validate_date() {
    // convert to Date objects to compare
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var date_object = new Date(date)
    var today = new Date();

    if (date_object <= today) {
        alert("Date cannot be today or the past!");
        // document.getElementById("date").value = "";
        date = ""; //doesn't reset
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" onblur="validate_date();">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("date").value='';` would seem more appropriate. The variable `date` is a readonly value

Comment: _"...when (I presume) they're the same thing?"_ - `date` is the _value_ (at the moment of execution) of the input element with the id `date` and not a reference to the `.value` property of that element.

Comment: Remove `.value` in the _`var date = ...` line and then use `date.value = ""` to reset the value

Answer (score 1):

when directly selecting an attribute of a DOM element, the variable becomes an independent entity.

By selecting the element instead will allow access to change its attributes.

```js
function validate_date() {
  var date = document.getElementById("date");
  date.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" onblur="validate_date();">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use inline JS pass in the event to the function, then pick up the value from that. Then you can reset the value. This way you don't need an id on the input.

```js
function validate_date(e) {
    var date = e.value;
    var date_object = new Date(date);
    var today = new Date();
    if (date_object <= today) {
      alert("Date cannot be today or the past!");
      e.value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" onblur="validate_date(this);">
```

Comment: How is the id relevent for this question? It's not relevent where the DOM element comes from, if OP got that reference from `.getElementById()` or from the event object/argument...

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about @Andreas.

Comment: Your answer works, but the explanation doesn't explain anything useful. _"This way you don't need an id on the input."_ - How is this relevant for this question?